# Looking for the PHP-equivalent of getElementById and innerHTML

Tags: php, javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am looking for the PHP equivalent of the Javascript function getElementById() and innerHTML. Basically, how can I edit the content of certain ID's in the document? Thanks.

Comment: you can only edit the content with PHP before it is sent to client. Not really sure what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: if you're building the DOM using php, you can do so. perform a google search for "dom php getelementbyid"

Comment: If you're using DOMDocument http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Comment: If the OP could articulate why he is trying to do this, we could give a helpful answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. PHP is sever side and can't operate on the document after it has been rendered.

Comment: Unless you use PHP to generate JavaScript. :)

Comment: The OP didn't mention he wants it *after*.

Comment: That is valid. I made a large assumption based on the comparison to Jscript. If he says he wants to parse the HTML file I'll change my answer.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean, but what I wanted to do is dinamically change a website without leaving it.

Answer (score 9):

`getElementById()` is available [via DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php).

`innerHTML()` is not, but it's possible to simulate it:

```
$innerHTML = '';
foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
  $innerHTML .= $node->ownerDocument->saveXML($child);
}
```

If your PHP version supports it, you can make use of [`saveHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) instead of [`saveXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php).

Comment: Are you sure you 're not fueling the OP's misconception about what these functions might actually *do* in PHP?

Comment: @Jon: If you want to express that the question can benefit from clarification, I'm with you. But even if so, it would remain to clarify if this can not be done within PHP, e.g. via output buffers.